# Употребление слова смазывать

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно использовать слово смазывать, когда речь идет о нанесении яйца на выпечку? Мне почему-то показалось странным услышать "смазать яйцом", так как, насколько я знаю, оно не используется в данном случае для придания свойств скольжения. К тому же яйцо сворачивается при температурной обработке. Уместнее кажется сказать "покрыть яйцом" или "нанести слой из ...".

Comment: Смазывают яйцом не раскаленную сковородку или лист, а выпечку. У них абсолютно разная температура. Так что яйцо не свернется)

Answer (score 1):

Из словаря

СМАЗАТЬ 1. что (чем). Покрыть слоем чего-л. жирного или жидкого; намазать, помазать. С. дверные петли. С. царапину йодом. С. руки кремом. С. волосы бальзамом. С. сапоги гуталином. Забыл с. ружьё.

Так что выпечку можно смазывать любой жидкой массой: яйцом, желтком, а также взбитым белком или яйцом.